# Why I can't capture the WIndows native message using winEvent virtual function?

Tags: qt, message

I wrote a simple Qt application to capture the Windows native message using the Qt GUI framework. I overrode the QCoreApplication::winEvent(MSG *, LONG )virtual function in my MainFrame class, but when I launch the application, the winEvent doesn't work properly, the code is like this:

```
 MainFrame.h
class MainFrame : public QMainWindow 
{
    public:
        MainFrame(QWidget *parent = NULL);
        ~MainFrame();
    private:
        virtual bool winEvent(MSG *, LONG);
};
MainFrame.cpp
bool MainFrame::winEvent(MSG *msg, LONG lResult)
{
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, NULL, "winEvent");

    return(true);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The signiture isn't right:

```
virtual bool winEvent(MSG *, LONG *);
```